# How to Screenshot programmatically with custom drawable

Tags: android

I'm taking screenshots using the code below.

Inside the layout I am using a custom drawable. The problem is that the bitmap shows everything as expected, except the custom drawable which looks kind of messed up.

I know the problem is related to the drawable. but I don't know what it is.

` View view = app.getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`
```

Thank you for your help, Niv

Comment: it must take screenshot of whole lay out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i figure it out.

the problem was that inside the onDraw in the custom drawable i used the 'canvas.getWidth()' instead of 'getBounds().width();'